# Make display use templates as displayfor would

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a type CurrencyAmount that contains both the amount and the currency.

I have an extension method to show this type in the views like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Display(this HtmlHelper html, Quipu.Eba.Model.CurrencyAmount currencyAmount, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    String value = currencyAmount.Amount.ToString("N2") + " " + currencyAmount.Currency.IsoCode;
    return new MvcHtmlString(value);
}
```

Then in the view I call it like this:

```
Html.Display(TransferAmount)
```

My problem now, in case I want to call this property with DisplayFor, I should write a template meaning duplicating the code.

How can I make my method Display to try to find if there is a template, like DisplayFor would do?

This way I could unify the calls from Display and DisplayFor to access the same template.

Comment: why don't you just only use `DisplayFor`?

Comment: Because where I call this display is inside a loop like "foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
               {Html.Display(order.TransferAmount);}" . I have no chance to use the model as required in displayfor in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `DisplayFor` for everything and add the partial view:

**Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\CurrencyAmount.cshtml**

```
@model Quipu.Eba.Model.CurrencyAmount

@(Model.Amount.ToString("N2") + " " + Model.Currency.IsoCode)
```

Finally, in your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransferAmount)
```

Comment: What if you have for example a loop like "foreach (var order in Model.Orders) {}" and then you want to use displayfor for order.TransferAmount?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => order.TransferAmount)`, just like any other foreach loop using `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor`.

Comment: This works. I finally followed another approach though, so I can call both display and displayfor. I simply added a template and in the template `@model Quipu.Eba.Model.CurrencyAmount
@Html.Display(Model)` . But thanks to show me the way :)

Comment: But you don't *need* both. There's no scenario where `DisplayFor` wouldn't work. Extending `HtmlHelper` is great, and there's scenarios where it's truly necessary, but in general, it's always better to use something built in, like `DisplayFor`. There's no additional namespace to include, no additional code to test, etc.

Comment: But check out my helper: `public static MvcHtmlString Display(this HtmlHelper html, CurrencyAmount currencyAmount, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
 String value = currencyAmount.Amount.ToString("N2") + " " + currencyAmount.Currency.IsoCode;
 if (htmlAttributes != null)
 {
  var span = new TagBuilder("span");
  var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes) as IDictionary<string, object>;
  span.MergeAttributes(attributes);
  span.SetInnerText(value);
  return new MvcHtmlString(span.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
 }
 return new MvcHtmlString(value);
}`

Comment: If you use htmlAttributes I think this is more of an elegant solution